# I would like to disable screen turning off when locking my screen on Debian 9

Tags: debian, display, multiple-monitors

I am having issues with my HP laptop in combination with docking station and external screen. Every time when I lock my screen, my both screens turn of. The next time when I move my mouse to unlock it, the laptop screen turns on but the external stays black.

After few seconds the external screen is turned on but then both screens turn of and on again in a loop. It takes around 1 minute that both screens are on again. Looks like a timeout issue.
When both screens are on again, all my windows are moved back to the laptop screen.

I would like to disable screen going off when I lock my laptop. How can I disable this?
I already disabled screen turn off in the Display settings, but this does not prevent the screen from going off when I lock my laptop.

This problem does not occur on Windows. I am running Debian 9 with Gnome 3.

Comment: Use another locker, like [xtrlock](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/xtrlock)

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Privacy > Screen Lock, then choose a period of time to wait before turning off.